# How to parse an XML attribute string and not lose white space characters

Tags: java, xml

I have a string in this format :

```
<params   text="To apply for and obtain a loan from Cash4Rent, Inc., you must agree to receive all information and disclosures regarding your loan electronically prior to submitting your loan application. 

The following information will be provided by electronic communication." 
/>
```

As you make see it has specific line breaks and spaces in the value of xml node "text". I am trying to parse through the XML string and print it out on my website. But as I parse through it, it loses the white spaces and prints out as a single line. How may I keep the format even after parsing it.. Below is my code.

Java Class:

```
public class XMLParser {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException{
    String inputXml = <params   text="To apply for and obtain a loan from Cash4Rent, Inc., you must agree to receive all information and disclosures regarding your loan electronically prior to submitting your loan application. The following information will be provided by electronic communication." />";System.out.println(inputXml);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = null;
    dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(inputXml));
    ArrayList<String> nodeNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> nodeValueList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Document doc = db.parse(is);
        for(int i=0 ; i<doc.getDocumentElement().getAttributes().getLength() ; i++ ){
           nodeNameList.add(doc.getDocumentElement().getAttributes().item(i).getNodeName());
           nodeValueList.add(doc.getDocumentElement().getAttributes().item(i).getNodeValue());
        }        
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // handle SAXException
    }
}    }
```

Result :

```
[text]
[To apply for and obtain a loan from Cash4Rent, Inc., you must agree to receive all information and disclosures regarding your loan electronically prior to submitting your loan application. The following information will be provided by electronic communication.]
```

Desired result:

```
[text]
[To apply for and obtain a loan from Cash4Rent, Inc., you must agree to receive all information and disclosures regarding your loan electronically prior to submitting your loan application. 

The following information will be provided by electronic communication.]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Attribute Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types)

> 3.3.1 Attribute Types
>
> XML attribute types are of three kinds: a string type, a set of tokenized types, and enumerated types. The string type may take any literal string as a value; the tokenized types are more constrained. The validity constraints noted in the grammar are applied after the attribute value has been normalized as described in 3.3.3 Attribute-Value Normalization.

and  [Attribute-Value Normalization](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#AVNormalize)

> 3.3.3 Attribute-Value Normalization
>
> Before the value of an attribute is passed to the application or checked for validity, the XML processor must normalize the attribute value by applying the algorithm below, or by using some other method such that the value passed to the application is the same as that produced by the algorithm.
>
> 1. All line breaks must have been normalized on input to #xA as described in 2.11 End-of-Line Handling, so the rest of this algorithm operates on text normalized in this way.
> 2. Begin with a normalized value consisting of the empty string.
> 3. For each character, entity reference, or character reference in the unnormalized attribute value, beginning with the first and continuing to the last, do the following:
>
>    - For a character reference, append the referenced character to the normalized value.
>    - For an entity reference, recursively apply step 3 of this algorithm to the replacement text of the entity.
>    - For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space character (#x20) to the normalized value.
>    - For another character, append the character to the normalized value.

Comment: It should be pointed out that the above links and citations are from the XML 1.0 specification.  Newlines, along with all other sequences of whitespace, are normalized in attribute values.  However, it is possible to place a newline sequence in an attribute value as a character entity, such as `<params text="Line one&#xa;&#xa;Line two"/>`.

Comment: do you think you can share a code example with me please?